# (is there/how to make) a package/macro like `enumerate` but for whole document sectioning

Tags: sectioning, packages, enumerate, counters, package-writing

I just discovered the `enumerate` package, what excited me because some time ago I was wondering about something similar (options where `a` stands for `\alph{<counter>}`, `A` for `\Alph{<counter>}`, `i` for `\roman{<counter>}`, etc.) but for the sectionning of the whole document. That is, to copy the notation of teacher while transcripting my history lessons, use something like `\usepackage[I/1/I/A/1/a]{sectioning}` (with maybe some additionnal syntax to specify when we want each counter to be reset to 0) instead of always writing

```
\renewcommand{\thepart}{Tema \Roman{part}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection .\Alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection .\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\thesubsubsection .\alph{paragraph}}
```

I formerly abandoned that idea because at time I didn’t know how to write a macro for a such thing (especially the `a`-to-`\alph{<actual-counter>}`-like part), but now not only I’m asking myself if a such package doesn’t already exist, but also if otherwise there aren’t already packages that could help me try to write one like that, as `enumerate` package do for `enumerate` environment (I’m also wondering if the same could be applied to `enumerate` and sub-`enumerate` environments).

So in brief, my question is: are there packages doing that or something like, and otherwise are there packages which could help me to achieve that or something like?

Comment: If you find the package `enumerate` sophisticated, then have a look at `enumitem` ;-) (No, I am not the author of `enumitem` ;-))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such package but perhaps, this code will lead to a package (given I have some time to improve the code and write the package)

Updated version

Syntax:

- `I` etc. uses just the counter formatter as requested by the O.P.
- `I+` etc. prepends the previous `\the...` formatter, e.g. `\thesubsection` will be used then as `\thesection \Roman{subsection}`
- `I+.` will add a dot before `\Roman{...}`.

It's not optimal so far, but working

---

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_galex_default_seq
\newcommand{\filldefaultseq}{%
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_galex_default_seq {/} {I+/A/I/A/1/a/i}
}

\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_sectionname_seq {part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\tl_gset:Nn \g_prepart_name {\space}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_prechapter_name {\thepart}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_presection_name {\thechapter}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_presubsection_name {\thesection}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_presubsubsection_name {\thesubsection}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_preparagraph_name {\thesubsubsection}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_presubparagraph_name {\theparagraph}

\tl_gset:Nn \g_part_structurename {Tema}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_chapter_structurename {}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_section_structurename {}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_subsection_structurename {}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_subsubsection_structurename {}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_paragraph_structurename {}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_subparagraph_structurename {}


\NewDocumentCommand{\ChangeCounterFormats}{o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {/} {#1}
  }{
    \seq_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_galex_default_seq
  }
  \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_sectionname_seq {%
    \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
    \str_case_x:nn {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\l_tmpa_int}}{%
      {I+.}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name}.\Roman{##1}}}
      {i+.}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name}.\roman{##1}}}
      {A+.}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name}.\Alph{##1}}}
      {a+.}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name}.\alph{##1}}}
      {1+.}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name}.\arabic{##1}}}
      {I+}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name} \Roman{##1}}}
      {i+}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name} \roman{##1}}}
      {A+}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name} \Alph{##1}}}
      {a+}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name} \alph{##1}}}
      {1+}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name} \arabic{##1}}}
      {I}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\Roman{##1}}}
      {i}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\roman{##1}}}
      {a}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\alph{##1}}}
      {A}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\Alph{##1}}}
      {1}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\arabic{##1}}}
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\filldefaultseq

\ChangeCounterFormats[I+/A/1+./i+./1+./i+./a+.]

\part{Foo}

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\paragraph{First paragraph}
\subparagraph{First subparagraph}



\part{Foo}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\paragraph{Second paragraph}
\subparagraph{Second subparagraph}


\chapter{Third chapter}
\section{Third section}
\subsection{Third subsection}
\subsubsection{Third subsubsection}
\paragraph{Third paragraph}
\subparagraph{Third subparagraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update 2016/02/27**

I created a `secfmt.sty` to change the counter formatting styles and a driver file.

Some macro names have been changed and I added `\StoreOriginalCounterFormats` and `\RestoreOriginalCounterFormats` macros which store `\thepart` etc. and restore them (if needed)

`secfmt.sty`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProvidesPackage{secfmt}

\RequirePackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Data section 
\seq_new:N \g_secfmt_default_seq
\seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_secfmt_sectionname_seq {part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}


\@ifclassloaded{memoir}{%
  \seq_gput_left:Nn \g_secfmt_sectionname_seq {book}
  \seq_gput_left:Nn \g_secfmt_default_seq {A}
}{}


\tl_gset:Nn \g_prebook_name {} % Only relevant for `memoir.cls`

\@ifclassloaded{memoir}{%
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_prepart_name {\thebook}
}{
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_prepart_name {\space}
}

\tl_gset:Nn \g_prechapter_name {\thepart}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_presection_name {\thechapter}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_presubsection_name {\thesection}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_presubsubsection_name {\thesubsection}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_preparagraph_name {\thesubsubsection}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_presubparagraph_name {\theparagraph}

\tl_gset:Nn \g_book_structurename {Book}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_part_structurename {Tema}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_chapter_structurename {}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_section_structurename {}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_subsection_structurename {}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_subsubsection_structurename {}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_paragraph_structurename {}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_subparagraph_structurename {}

%% Function section

\NewDocumentCommand{\StoreOriginalCounterFormats}{}{%
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_secfmt_sectionname_seq {%
    \cs_gset_eq:cc {cs_orig_the##1} {the##1}
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\RestoreOriginalCounterFormats}{}{%
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_secfmt_sectionname_seq {%
    \cs_gset_eq:cc {the##1} {cs_orig_the##1} 
  }
}

\AtBeginDocument{\StoreOriginalCounterFormats}

\NewDocumentCommand{\CreateDefaultCounterFormats}{o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \g_secfmt_default_seq {/} {#1}
  }{%
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \g_secfmt_default_seq {/} {I+/A/I/A/1/a/i}
  }
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\ChangeCounterFormats}{o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {/} {#1}
  }{
    \seq_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_seq \g_secfmt_default_seq
  }
  \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int % dummy counter
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_secfmt_sectionname_seq {%
    \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
    \str_case_x:nn {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\l_tmpa_int}}{%
      {I+.}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name}.\Roman{##1}}}
      {i+.}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name}.\roman{##1}}}
      {A+.}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name}.\Alph{##1}}}
      {a+.}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name}.\alph{##1}}}
      {1+.}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name}.\arabic{##1}}}
      {I+}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name} \Roman{##1}}}
      {i+}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name} \roman{##1}}}
      {A+}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name} \Alph{##1}}}
      {a+}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name} \alph{##1}}}
      {1+}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\tl_use:c {g_##1_structurename}\tl_use:c {g_pre##1_name} \arabic{##1}}}
      {I}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\Roman{##1}}}
      {i}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\roman{##1}}}
      {a}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\alph{##1}}}
      {A}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\Alph{##1}}}
      {1}{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the##1\endcsname{\arabic{##1}}}
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\endinput
```

`driver.tex`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{secfmt}

\CreateDefaultCounterFormats%

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\ChangeCounterFormats[I+/A/1+./i+./1+./i+./a+.]

\part{First Part}

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\paragraph{First paragraph}
\subparagraph{First subparagraph}



\part{Second part}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\paragraph{Second paragraph}
\subparagraph{Second subparagraph}


\chapter{Third chapter}
\section{Third section}
\subsection{Third subsection}
\subsubsection{Third subsubsection}
\paragraph{Third paragraph}
\subparagraph{Third subparagraph}

\RestoreOriginalCounterFormats

\part{Third part}

\chapter{Third chapter}
\section{Third section}
\subsection{Third subsection}
\subsubsection{Third subsubsection}
\paragraph{Third paragraph}
\subparagraph{Third subparagraph}


\chapter{Fourth chapter}
\section{Fourth section}
\subsection{Fourth subsection}
\subsubsection{Fourth subsubsection}
\paragraph{Fourth paragraph}
\subparagraph{Fourth subparagraph}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Impressive, I wouldn’t have expected a so complete answer! :D Yet it’s really verbose code (seems Java) and that require to use (and know how to use) `xparse`… Is `xparse` use optimal or could it be as efficient with simpler TeX/plainTeX code (maybe copying some of `enumerate` code with recursive parsing)? Also I don’t understand the usage of « . » which could also be the default I think… And the « + » seems to have no effect on TOC. Anyway that’s just awesome, I just need to understand that verbose xparse code ^^

Comment: @galex-713: I don't understand. I showed the `ToC` in the image above -- it has the desired effect. Do you have the correct `tocdepth` setting? `xparse` is optimal, since it uses the new LaTeX 3 features, which simplies a lot of the code. Please do not stick to `enumerate` -- that's a totally different setup

Comment: For the ToC i tried it and I thought some change didn’t have effect, but after your comment I tried again and it works, so I probably forgot to compile once more ^^" For `xparse` I said it because it seemed to require really verbose code, and I supposed that since `xparse` is probably written from some LaTeX, written from some TeX, it would be possible to achieve the same thing with less code… otherwise why `enumerate` isn’t using it? For the LaTeX3 features, does it means LaTeX3 adds primitives that aren’t doable as well with TeX and aren’t used within enumerate?

Comment: @galex-713 -- Actually the code for `enumerate` in `latex.ltx` is quite complicated. But `enumerate` is a list, which is very different (in the *TeX world) from code for sectioning. If they were the same thing, then a LaTeX document would only be a giant list, which is untrue. What Christian has done here is given you a whole new set of code that gives you the convenient `\ChangeCounterFormats` macro. (And he can't put it behind the scenes the way it is in `latex.ltx` or, for lists, in `enumitem.sty`.) Finally, LaTeX3 does not 'add' primitives in the true sense of the word.

Comment: @galex-713 -- Of course, *you* can put the relevant code in a separate file called (say) `mypackage.sty` and then simply load it with `\usepackage{mypackage}`.

Comment: @galex-713: I provided the 'package' `secnum.sty` and a driver file.

Comment: @jon: Thanks for explaining to galex-713

Comment: @jon Ok so LaTeX3 provide new low-level more efficient macros ^^ and I was speaking about the `enumerate` **package**, and I was just speaking of inspiring from it to do the same kind of thing (not regarding lists but the `a`-to-`\alph{<counter>}`-like thing, and here `\thesection`, etc., modification seems to works as `\labelenumi\+`’s one) + recursivity (I mean without verbose high level `xparse`), not “reuse code from it” ^^" so thank you too :), for the rest I knew

Comment: @galex-713: Please consider to accept my answer to appreciate the amount of work

Comment: Oh yeah sure sorry forgot/procrastined that (just did +1 before), done ^^